# What is the status of this question?

Tags: discussion, bug

This question, [Getting unwanted NullPointerException in ternary operator - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147247/getting-unwanted-nullpointerexception-in-ternary-operator-why) , it's status is [duplicate]:

[image]

But in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) page, it's [on hold]:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's on hold as a duplicate.

These things aren't mutually exclusive. If a question gains enough close votes, it gets put on hold for some time until it gets closed, and it can get put on hold as a duplicate.

Apparently, this is displayed differently on different pages.

Comment: `Apparently, this is displayed differently on different pages.` Why is this needed?

Comment: @Sun That's likely unintended, and not needed at all. The way duplicates have been displayed has changed over the years (at first, the duplicate message was edited into the post by community, and duplicates had no further special status (no dupehammer, for example)).  If you want to get that addressed, you can open up a [meta-tag:bug] or [meta-tag:feature-request], whichever you feel is most applicable to the situation. MSE would be more appropriate than MSO, since it's likely network-wide.